# Add extra custom glyphicons to Bootsrap 3

Tags: css, less, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

What is the best way to add extra custom glyphicons to Bootstrap 3?

I see that the icons are now defined in a font.

Comment: This might be overkill for you, but give [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/) a look over. You might also be able to fork the Bootstrap GlyphIcons repo and build your own font with custom icons

Comment: @Bojangles Thank you for your answer!
Good idea to **REQUEST** an icon on FontAwesome. Spending my time on it ;)

My toughts changing every day with Bootstrap. Was thinking in old style. (Create by myself even having low skills and implement it. "time-consuming")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bojangles commented, you can go for forking the font and adding glyphs, but beware that font creation is a  taxing job, especially if you are new to it.

For most common uses go with FontAwesome, or alternately you can create your image sprites and map new icon classes to this sprite.

Comment: Very nice didnt knew about FontAwesome. Getting in touch with it ;)

Comment: Awesome! Removed Bootstrap 3 icons from LESS file and included FontAwesome icons from CDN. FontAwesome gives more icon choise and site is much faster.